# How can I bind an azure function input, based on a property in the function trigger?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to create an Azure function that is triggered by an Event Hub message.  I also want to use a Document from DocumentDb, taking the DocumentId from the content of the trigger message (the event hub message).
I don't see how this is possible and I doubt if it is, but I wanted to give this a try.
In the input, I selected the DocumentDB and in the DocumentId input box (defaulted to {documentId}, I entered {myEventHubMessage.DocumentId}, where myEventHubMessage is the name of my trigger and DocumentId the json property in the content of the message.

Any idea if this is possible and how I could workaround this (without hardcoding DocDb connection strings in my function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Below is a C# example, showing first the code, then the binding metadata. For other languages like Node, the binding metadata would be the same, just the code differs. The DocumentDB binding binds to the **DocId** property of the incoming message via binding expression **{DocId}**.

Here's the code:

```
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using System;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(MyEvent evt, MyDocument document, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed event: {evt.Id}");
    log.Info($"Document {document.Id} loaded. Value {document.Value}");
}

public class MyEvent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DocId { get; set; }
}

public class MyDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the binding metadata:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "evt",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "testhub",
      "connection": "<your connection>"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentdb",
      "name": "document",
      "databaseName": "<your database>",
      "collectionName": "<your collection>",
      "id": "{DocId}",
      "connection": "<your connection>",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```